# Salesforce integration with php

Tags: php

Afternoon,

I am currently having an issue displaying data from newly added fields within my php page?

Here is an example.
[http://cvm.org.uk/salesforce/sport-details?id=003D000001r6G3tIAE][1]

```
<?php
// session_start() has to go right at the top, before any output!
session_start();
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0');
?>
<?php require_once('../Connections/salesforceconnect.php');?>

<body>
<?php $query = sprintf("select firstname, lastname, Email, MailingCity, MailingState, Publicity_Description_del__c, Profile_Image__c, Facebook_URL__c, Football_Club__c  from contact where id = '%s'", $_GET['id']);
$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
foreach($response->records as $record) { ?>
<font size="+3"><?php echo $record->FirstName." ".$record->LastName ?></font><br />
<img src="<?php echo $record->Profile_Image__c ?>" width="150px" height="150px" hspace="10px" vspace="10px" align="left"/>
<table style="margin-left: 160px !important;" width="367" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col"><h2 align="left">Basic Information</h2></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="85"><b><font size="1">Football Club:</font></b></td>
    <td width="272"><font size="2"><?php echo $record->Football_Club__c ?> &lt;&lt; Missing information</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b><font size="1">Home Town:</font></b></td>
    <td><font size="2"><?php echo $record->MailingCity ?>, <?php echo $record->MailingState ?></font></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table width="637" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col"><h2 align="left">Basic Information</h2></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="85"><b><font size="1">About <?php echo $record->FirstName ?>:</font></b></td>
    <td width="542"><font size="2"><?php echo $record->Publicity_Description_del__c ?></font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b><font size="1">Email:</font></b></td>
    <td><p><font size="2"><?php echo $record->Email ?></font></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><p><font size="2"><a href="<?php echo $record->Facebook_URL__c ?>">Join <?php echo $record->Football_Club__c ?> Football Group</a></font> <font size="2">&lt;&lt; Missing information</font> </p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Missing data is the in the image and where shown on webpage.

Any advice? :S

Many thanks Kirsty

Comment: Could you post your code in using the Preformatted text tool? Makes it a bit easier to read and inspect! :) One thing I would check, assuming you're using SOAP, check that your WSDL file is up date. You can download this by going to Setup > Develop > API and choosing either the Partner or Enterprise WSDL file. Replace this and let us know if you get anything different. The WSDL file effectively describes things like fields, objects within it. So I'd wager this is definitely at least one reason you're not pulling anything through. Especially if they are, as you say "newly added fields".

Comment: It may also be worth doing print_r($response) and sharing that code with us, to see what Salesforce is returning.

Comment: I will give updating the WSDL file a try,  I haven't touched that file since I set the connection up over a year ago.

Comment: Perfect. I've put this as an answer to the question. I'd say this is the most likely reason at present.

Comment: I've updated the file,.....

Comment: Okay great, what's the result of that? Can you perform a print_r($response) and post that response in your question (assuming that's still not fixed it)?

Comment: I have added the code, but I am not sure how to perform a print_r($response)?

Comment: Under _$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);_ just type _print_r($response);_ within the delimiters.

Comment: I have added that as requested.

Comment: Can you share with us what that's printing? Basically that's giving you the raw response from Salesforce that might tell us what it is or what it is not getting.

Comment: I can link you up with the web pages, I have added it to. http://cvm.org.uk/salesforce/sport-details?id=003D000001r6G3tIAE - http://cvm.org.uk/salesforce/sport

Comment: Okay. From that error it seems Client mismatch between referencing the Partner and/or Enterprise scripts. Can you post your salesforceconnect.php script (be sure to remove any credentials/keys before posting).

Comment: Strange. I've just tested your code against my own environment it worked fine. It may be worth updating your soapclient folder by going to [link](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP) and downloading the latest version (don't forget to re-replace the WSDL files). Let us know how that works.

Comment: I have just done a further update on the folder, and it appears to be working....

Comment: Good to hear! :) Glad to help.

Comment: Instead of using the initial Enterprise WSDL that was available I selected configure Enterprise Package Version Settings, and then downloaded the new version. :) Thank you so so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Ah package control settings. Makes sense! For future reference though typically if you're not pulling anything through that file is likely the reason. Tripped me up many times! Glad to help! Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using SOAP. If the fields are, as you say,

> newly added fields

One reason could be that your WSDL files are out of date. To download this, go to

> Setup > Develop > API

Choose either the Partner or Enterprise WSDL file to download (if you're unsure, downloading both shouldn't hurt) and replace the files in your 'soapclient' folder.

The WSDL files effectively describe objects, fields et al. So if this is out of date and those objects and fields aren't described, they can't be accessed.

**Edit:**
It may be worth updating your soapclient folder by going [here](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP) and downloading the latest version (don't forget to re-replace the WSDL files).